# DynamoDB C# - Fetch data inside a parameter of another class

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb

I have two classes:

```
[DynamoDBTable("Book")]
    public class Book
    {
        [DynamoDBHashKey]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    }
    
    
[DynamoDBTable("Section")]
    public class Section
    {
        [DynamoDBHashKey]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I perform an operation in DynamoDB to check if the value exists inside Book -> Sections

If there is an Identifier in the list of sections.

The purpose of my operation is to alert the user if he tries to delete a section that has a linked book.

A serious check operation before doing the line below:

```
_context.DeleteAsync<Section>(identifier).GetAwaiter();
```

I tried to use the scan condition, but without success.

I also tried to perform a query mapping operation, but I think I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Sections List in the Book class have to be a `List<Section>`?

If it was just `List<string> SectionIdentifiers`, then you could just use `SectionIdentifiers.Contains(someID)`. In this case you've reduced what you're looking up to string literals so you don't have to worry about your custom Section class.